# doctrine repositery FindBy Array with a var

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:CAP270ColisProduits')
    ->findBy(array('idcolis' => array($listedesidcolis)));
```

with $listedesidcolis = '49','55'
it return only one result

if i do:

```
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:CAP270ColisProduits')
    ->findBy(array('idcolis' => array('49','55')));
```

I ve got my two results

Comment: `$listedesidcolis = '49','55'` is not valid PHP

Comment: You could try dump out the sql just to verify but I'm speculating that Doctrine is smart enough to turn an array into a WHERE x IN() statement.  But yes, your first example is not valid php.  Always useful to post actual code.

Comment: thank you you are right
i build an array with $listedesidcolis 
and then ->findBy(array('idcolis' => $listedesidcolis)); 
works fine